# android FID & GUID (UUID) remains the same after updates of the same application?

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier

I intend to use FID/GUID as a unique ID as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#java).
will this unique ID remain the same after I update the app to a newer version of itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not get changed until and unless you delete and install the application again. (GUID)